# Cannot reactivate RAID-5 volume: The size of the plex member is invalid

Tags: software-raid, windows, raid5, diskpart

We had a 3-drive Windows Server 2008 R2 RAID-5 fail (operating in redundancy mode):

- WDC 1 TB
- WDC 1 TB
- WDC 1 TB

We removed the failed hard drive, and put a WDC 1 TB drive (that we had standing by) into the machine.

When launched, **Disk Manager**, asked permission to *"initialize"* the disk as either:

- Master Boot Record (MBR)
- Guid Partition Table (GPT)

We initialized the disk as **GPT**, converted it to **dynamic**, and tried to use the **Repair Volume** command - except it was greyed out. *(which is a terrifying thing on a failed production server hosting 3 virtual servers)*

---

i tried from the `diskpart` command line tool. First we look for our RAID-5 volume that is in `Failed Rd` mode:

```
DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     E   VMs (Raid5)  NTFS   RAID-5      1863 GB  Failed Rd
  Volume 1     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 2         System Rese  NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 3     C                NTFS   Partition   1862 GB  Healthy    Boot
```

There, **Volume 0**. Make that our active context:

```
DISKPART> select volume 0

Volume 0 is the selected volume.
```

Now we need to find the disk we will be repairing the volume with:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB      0 B   *
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB   931 GB        *
  Disk 2    Online         1863 GB      0 B
  Disk 3    Online          931 GB      0 B   *
  Disk M0   Missing            0 B      0 B   *
```

The disk with 931 GB free, **Disk 1**. Now we just need to repair the volume:

```
DISKPART> repair disk=1

Virtual Disk Service error:
The size of the plex member is invalid.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was very subtle, and a horrible design idea by Microsoft.

The two original Western Digital Caviar Black 1 TB drives were listed as `931.51 GB`:

[image]

But the new disk was **931.39 GB** (120 MB to small) - even though the drives are the same size.

In a flash of inspiration i realized that **Guid Partition Table** might take up more space than a **Master Boot Record** partition. We converted the drive back to **MDR**.

The drive then appeared to be **`931.51 GB`**, and the **Repair Volume** option was no longer greyed out.

So, when **Disk Manager** tells you **nothing** about what the problem is - it might because there is no drive large enough to act as a replacement. And `The size of the plex member is invalid.` might mean that the drive is not large enough to hold the needed volume.

---

i especially liked the part where Disk Management told us nothing at all.

Comment: If this is resolved, please mark it as such by clicking on the tick mark so that it turns green. Thanks!